# Button methods do not work after adding it programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

Alright, I'm trying to make a quick method to create buttons & edit them.

I've declared the buttons

```
UIButton *button1, *button2;
```

After that I made my method to create buttons.

```
-(void)addButton:(NSString *)name :(NSString *)buttonId :(UIButton *)button {
    int height;
    height = buttonId.intValue;
    height = height *45;

    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 120+height, 160.0, 40.0);
    [self.view addSubview:button];

}
```

inside `-viewDidLoad` I added called the method

```
[self addButton:@"Button one!" : @"1" : button1];
```

Everything works now, the button shows up and everything. However, if I try to change the alpha of the button or hide it, it doesn't work.

such as `button1.alpha = 0.1;` doesn't work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Be sure to add a strong reference of the buttons to your variables, or else they will be nil and will produce the symptoms you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method signature should look like this:

```
-(void)addButton:(NSString *)name :(NSString *)buttonId :(UIButton **)outButton {
```

or, better,

```
- (UIButton *)addButtonWithTitle:(NSString *)title index:(NSInteger)buttonID {
```

In the former case, the implementation would be something like

```
…
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
*outButton = button;
```

In the latter,

```
int height = buttonID * 45;
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
…
return button;
```

where you’d then initially call it with, say,

```
button1 = [self addButtonWithTitle:@"Button one!" index:1];
```